# Multiplying a Python MaskedColumn

Tags: python, astropy

I'm reading in a .html file of data, and all I'd like to do is multiply the data['ra'] column by 15. However, I'm getting an error::

```
>>> data = ascii.read("Ldwarf.html", format="html", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")  
>>> data

<Table masked=True length=919>
designation ra  decl    
2MASS J00011217+1535355 0.0200472   +15.593194  
2MASS J00025097+2454141 0.0474917   +24.903917  
2MASS J00040288-6410358 0.0674667   -64.176611
```

and

```
>>> data['ra'] 
<MaskedColumn name='ra' dtype='str10' length=919>
decimal hr
0.0200472
0.0474917
...
23.9783250
23.9993389

>>> data['ra'] = data['ra'].filled([-9.99])
>>> data['ra'] = data['ra']*15.

TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching 
types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

What is going on??

Comment: can you post the html file as well

Comment: http://ldwarf.ipac.caltech.edu/archive/version5/viewlist.php?table=ldwarf&format=html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the html file, there should be 918 rows but you get 919. The row with the definition of the units is read as the first data row and it messes everything. This is why you see the first "ra" as "decimal hr" instead of a number and the column data type is inferred as dtype='str10'.

You can use the "data_start" argument to discard the problematic row:

```
data = ascii.read("Ldwarf.html", 
                  format="html", 
                  encoding="ISO-8859-1", 
                  data_start=2)
```

Now the input types are inferred correctly and you should not have any problem multiplying by 15 the "ra".

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem, but I make up that data['ra'] does not contain a numerical type. It looks like an unicode string.

If it is the case, it could be solved by explicitly specifying the type before multiplying:

> data['ra'] = float(data['ra'])

EDIT: Ok, then it contains an array, so you need to modify the type in a compatible way:

> data['ra']= np.asarray(data['ra'], dtype='float64')

Comment: I now get:: TypeError: Only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 0):

It says that the `dtype` is `str10`.

Convert it to 64 bit real:

```
data['ra'] = data['ra'].astype(numpy.float64)
```

Comment: I now get:: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'decimal hr'

Comment: I have just seen Pepe's (nudomarinero) response. He correctly identifies the problem is the column name.